# Saving a changing amount of Values in a SQL-Database

Tags: android, sql-server

i am really stuck at this point of my android app development.
What i need is a way to save a changing amount of int or string-values (in a sql database). Yet im not even sure if this is the right approach, but let me explain:

In the app i am currently working on, you are able to create certain "events". Users should be able to apply for such events.

I have an external database with 2 tables:

1. first one for users - every user has a unique ID
2. second one for events - every event has a unique ID

I need each event to know what users applied for it. And i need each user to know what events they applied for. 
I was thinking to save the Event-IDs in the User-Table and vice versa.

I just dont know how to do that since the amount of applicants/ID's can change. Is there a way to save Arrays in the database which can easily be edited (e.g. +/- one ID) and read?

Is this even the right way? I am very happy for any advise!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would add a third table (e.g. UserEvents) to store which events a user has applied for, along with other relevant attributes (e.g. ApplicationTime, ApplicationStatus).  This association would have a foreign key relationship back to the related tables and resolve the many-to-many relationship between users and events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want is a many-to-many relationship. A user can be part of many events, and an event can have many users. That requires an additional table though:

- **Table:** User **Columns:** UserId, Name, ...
- **Table:** Event **Columns:** EventId, Name, ...
- **Table:** UserEvents **Columns:** UserId, EventId, ...

In the new table, *UserEvents*, you would store the UserId's and EventId's like this:

```
UserEvents
UserId   EventId
1        1
2        1
1        2
```

This means that if you selected *UserId 1*, the query would return *EventId 1 & 2*. If you selected *EventId 1* the query would return that *UserId 1 & 2* would be attending.

This is the standard and recommended way to deal with many-to-many. It's very flexible and can easily be scaled.

You could either use a Compound key (Composite Key) for this table, or create a column specifically as a Primary Key. The code below can be used, and manipulated, to create both your table and Compound/Composite key (I'm guessing on data types).

```
CREATE TABLE UserEvents
(
  [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
  [EventId] INT NOT NULL    
  CONSTRAINT PK_UserEvents PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([UserId], [EventId])
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. I created a new table with a Compound Key (UserId, EventId). I dont think there will be a problem when an User applies/signs up for an already existing event since the EventId is already given. But in case the Event is just being created by an User - a new row will be inserted into the event-table with an auto-incremented EventId. Since this ID is just being generated, how can i make sure to populate the UserEvent-Table with the same ID? Probably a stupid question, but i cant help it right now :-S

Comment: @henniboi In Sql Server you can use `@@IDENTITY` to get the last created id. If we look at it from the front-end: You can do an insert in _Event_, return the Id to the front-end and then directly do another insert to _UserEvents_ (using that Id, and the users id). It could also be done in  stored procedure, using @@IDENTITY between the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a third table (e.g. UserEvents) to store which events a user has applied for, along with other relevant attributes (e.g. ApplicationTime, ApplicationStatus).  This association would have a foreign key relationship back to the related tables and resolve the many-to-many relationship between users and events.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is called a "many-to-many" relationship between to tables which can only be resolved by the introduction of a third table between your two tables that stores the associations. 
This table would contain the User-ID and the Event-ID as foreign keys (and maybe additional information).